# how to auto include dependent dll when compile?

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, mingw

How to point compile executable to find dll inside system?

i'm compile with this command.

```
g++ -Wall helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe
```

but to run the executable i need to include some dll in same  folder.

how to make the program to point to system dll?

or to auto include dll when compile.

i'm not means static link. but dynamic link.

but when compile the dll auto copy to compile program path.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any DLLs then you need to do a static build (`--static`).

DLL dependancies are caused by functions being used that are in a specific DLL. So you can't just make it point to just any system DLL instead (unless you really do a static build or at least use `-static-libgcc` and/or `-static-libstdc++` to avoid using shared libraries for those libraries).

Or you can just distribute the DLL files in the same folder as the EXE file(s).
To copy all the `.dll` files your `.exe` depends on you can use You can use `copypedeps` with the `-r` flag from https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps